# Cannot edit values in already binded grid using web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am using web API to edit values from collection in MongoDB.I have added code to fetch values from mongodb and have called it in another to fetch the api to perform edit functionality.

When i click the edit option in grid. A system argument exception occures.
I think it happens when fetching the uri.It happens when id paramenter is not provided.But i have wriiten code to fetch id from db.. My error screen is screenshot below.

I am new to web api and mongo db!! please help.

**Contact.cs(Model class)**

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

**mongodbcontroller(Controller)**

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public Contact Edit(Contact contact)
    {
        var contactsList = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("contact");
        WriteConcernResult result;
        bool hasError = false;

        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Id))
            {
                IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", contact.Id);
                IMongoUpdate update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update
                    //.Set("Id",contact.Id)
                    .Set("Name", contact.Name)
                    .Set("Address", contact.Address)
                    .Set("Phone", contact.Phone)
                    .Set("Email", contact.Email);
                result = contactsList.Update(query, update);
                contactsList.Save(contact);

                hasError = result.HasLastErrorMessage;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.ToString();
        }


        if (!hasError)
        {
            return contact;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

**TestController(Consuming the api)**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //Contact contact = new Contact();
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61093/api/MongoDb/");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("edit?Id=" + contact.Id.ToString());
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Contact>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    contact = readTask.Result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


        return View(contact);


    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
    {

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61093/api/MongoDb/edit");
                //HTTP GET
                var putTask = client.PutAsJsonAsync<Contact>("contact",contact);
                putTask.Wait();

                var result = putTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }                     
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


        return View(contact);

    }

}
```

**Edit.cshtml(View)**

```
  @model TestApi.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My error page
[image: Error Page]

Comment: As per the error your Edit Get request is expecting an int but on the url it is a string. So `public ActionResult Edit(int id)` should be `public ActionResult Edit(string id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass in non-integer identifier back to Web Server thru http://localhost/.../Edit/Non-Integer-Identifier. MVC Route Handler cannot convert it to Integer for Action, 'Edit(int id)'.

1. Send the proper integer identifier.
2. Or, change the MvC Action to Edit(string id)

Comment: Thank you @ashokan